# Windows 10 right click freeze

Tags: windows-10

I just upgraded to windows 10 and everytime I right click on something (like a video file) to change something that window freezes.
Could someone explain what's causing the problem?

Comment: Did you have any programs that had their own context menu entries before you upgraded?

Comment: hmm maybe ccleaner

Comment: I believe CCleaner was updated for Windows 10, have you updated? Check other software for updates as well.